# Mostrar una serie de divs con javascript en ciclo for

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy tratando de mostrar una serie de elementos  al darle clic a un botón.

Tengo un solo botón y quiero irlos mostrando a medida voy presionando. Quiero mostrar el div ref2 en el primer clic y el ref3 en el segundo clic.

Lo que hice fue un ciclo for pero me los muestra todos al mismo tiempo al darle clic, no se porque esta pasando.
Alguien me puede decir porque el ciclo for no se cumple como estoy tratando de hacerlo?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>
        .oculto{
            display:none;
        }
        </style>
    <title>document</title>
</head>
<body>
                        <div class="container">

                            <h3>Referencias</h3><br>

                            <div id="ref1" class=""> <!-- Inicio Referencia -->
                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="nombreRef1">Nombre<small></small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nombreRef1"  name="nombreRef1" value="" class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div>
                            </div> <!--Final Referencia1 -->
                            <div id="ref2" class="oculto"> <!-- Inicio Referencia2 -->
                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="nombreRef2">Nombre 2<small></small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nombreRef2"  name="nombreRef2" value="" class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div>
                            </div> <!--Final Referencia2 -->
                            <div id="ref3" class="oculto"> <!-- Inicio Referencia3 -->
                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="nombreRef3">Nombre 3<small></small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nombreRef3"  name="nombreRef3" value="" class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div> 
                            </div> <!--Final Referencia3 -->

                            <br>
                            <input type="button" class="btn agregarbtn" value="Agregar Referencia">
                            <br>
                        </div>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script src="validaciones.js">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Mi código JavaScript "validaciones.js" es este:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".agregarbtn").click(function(){

        let element1= document.getElementById("ref2");
        let element2= document.getElementById("ref3");

        for(var contador=1;contador<=3;contador++){
            if(contador<=2){
                element1.classList.remove("oculto");
            } else if(contador<=3){
                element2.classList.remove("oculto");
            }
            contador++;
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Los div ya existen y estan ocultos, entonces con el primer click se muestra uno y con el segundo click el otro? es así?

Comment: @BetaM Los divs estan ocultos, pero al darle clic me muestra los 2 divs al mismo tiempo, si inicializo el contador en 0, solamente me muestra el div ref2, lo que quiero es mostrar uno al primer clic y el otro al siguiente clic. como explico en el Post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás sólo se debían hacer pequeños cambios en validaciones.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let element1= document.getElementById("ref2");
    let element2= document.getElementById("ref3");
    var contador=0;
    $(".agregarbtn").click(function(){
        contador++;
        if(contador==1){
            element1.classList.remove("oculto");
        }
        else if(contador==2){
            element2.classList.remove("oculto");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".agregarbtn").click(function(){

    let element1= document.getElementById("ref2");
    let element2= document.getElementById("ref3");

    if (element1.style.display === "") {
      element1.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      if (element2.style.display === "" && element1.style.display !== "none"){
        element2.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.oculto{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

                            <h3>Referencias</h3><br>

                            <div id="ref1" class=""> <!-- Inicio Referencia -->
                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="nombreRef1">Nombre<small></small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nombreRef1"  name="nombreRef1" value="" class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div>
                            </div> <!--Final Referencia1 -->
                            <div id="ref2" class="oculto"> <!-- Inicio Referencia2 -->
                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="nombreRef2">Nombre 2<small></small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nombreRef2"  name="nombreRef2" value="" class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div>
                            </div> <!--Final Referencia2 -->
                            <div id="ref3" class="oculto"> <!-- Inicio Referencia3 -->
                                <div class="col_one_third c-azul">
                                    <label for="nombreRef3">Nombre 3<small></small></label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nombreRef3"  name="nombreRef3" value="" class="sm-form-control ">
                                </div> 
                            </div> <!--Final Referencia3 -->

                            <br>
                            <input type="button" class="btn agregarbtn" value="Agregar Referencia">
                            <br>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Recuerda una explicación al código no cae mal